# Tracking down zombies with Xcode 5 on ios6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5, instruments

I have a zombie object somewhere in my code when it is run on iOS 6.1 but not in 7.

Unfortunately instruments will not run with zombies it pops up the following warning. "Zombies can only be run on devices with iOS 7 or later".

I don't really want to download an older version of Xcode as works internet is painfully slow.

What are some tips/tricks for hunting down the cause of this zombie as my normal goto approach is unavailable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

From the menu bar, choose Project > Scheme > Edit Scheme…  Click the Run item in the list on the left.  Then click the Diagnostics tab on the right.  Turn on the “Enable Zombie Objects” checkbox.  Run your app from Xcode.

[image: enable zombie objects checkbox]

Comment: Its won't detect zombies on a device with iOS 6.1, rather try zombies instrument on a 6.1 simulator. When zombies detected, Allocation pane would show a red mark and describe the location where zombies are found.

Comment: I already had zombies enabled it won't detect where its coming from. I am currently downloading simulator for 6.1 but its going to take about 4 hours :(. Hopefully it works.