# NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey: EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash-reports

Crashlog:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x12121212

libobjc.A.dylib - objc_msgSend - isEqual:
CoreFoundation  - -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
```

Code:

```
if (object) {
    [_objects setObject:object forKey:key];
}
```

When init of _objects happens earlier in code:

```
- (id)init {
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
         _objects = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     }
     return self;
}
```

Object can be nil value, thats why I'm checking if it exist:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *object = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

I'm not sure what exactly can cause it. Crash happens very rarely, I'm unable to reproduce it, however a few users got it. I assume something got deallocated, could it be that `_objects` is nil? Or whole controller got deallocated? Why I can see `isEqual` in the log?

Can this fix the issue?

```
if (object && _objects) {
    [_objects setObject:object forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Initialization of dictionary and object?

Comment: for object deallocation unable zombies objects in your xcode for more details.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109022/tracking-down-zombies-with-xcode-5-on-ios6

Comment: @Vive: are you sure your key will not be nil?

Comment: @Sunnyshah Yes, I'm using ARC. Don't zombies turn off automatically in release mode?

Comment: `NSDictionary` uses `isEqual` on the `key`. What is your `key`? What does it's `isEqual` method do? The rarity of the crash might be because a hash collision has to occur for the `isEqual` method to be called.

Comment: @Vatev isEqual must be the default method, I didn't overload it. I'm indeed counting hash for it. How to fix the issue if it comes from hash?

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `hash`? AFAIK the only requirement for `hash` is that two equal objects must have the same hash.

Comment: @Vatev I just realized, rare collisions can always happen in `hash`. I'm checking `![_objects objectForKey:identifier]` and it should be ok now. Thank you for your answer, can you post it separately? I would like to accept it.

Comment: I don't think that would be a solution - `objectForKey:` will do the same check. Hash collisions are normal and expected, thats why `NSDictionary` calls `isEqual` to make sure the objects are the same. Try to make your `hash` method always return 0 to reproduce the crash. Normally even with a `return 0` `hash` method the dictionary should work (the only difference is that it will get slow with a lot of objects).

Comment: @Vatev It's ok, I've check as you said, made `identifier = @"0"`. There is no crash if i check `objectForKey:` because I'm not trying to add different object for the same key. When I'm not adding anything to key, which exists, there is no crash. Can you please add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have checked not null condition for the dictionary and object value. Try to check nil condition for your key of object. There might be a case where key can be nil.

```
if (object && _objects && key) {
    [_objects setObject:object forKey:key];
}
```